# Grab all links from a page

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-match-all

I want to grab all links (href) from a page.

This is my actual code:

```
preg_match_all('/href=.([^"\' ]+)/i', $content, $anchor);
```

But this grabs only domains and subdomains (like `name.name.ex` or `name.ex`) but doesn't grab custom URLs like `name.ex/name/name.php`.

Can anyone please help with the regular expression?

Comment: You could list all of the domains (i.e. .com, .org, .net, etc.) and then preg_match_all them. Here's the wiki of all the TLDs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise against use of regular expression for this. I suggest that you use [`DOM`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse and get your results.

Below is an example for this using `DOM` and `XPath`

```
$html = '<a href="name.ex/name/name.php">text</a>
         <a href="foo.com">foobar</a>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $link) {
   $links[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
}

print_r($links);
```

See [`Working demo`](https://eval.in/81927)

Answer (score 1):

It is more easy to use DOMDocument:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$linkNodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($linkNodes as $linkNode) {
    $urls[] = $linkNode->getAttribute('href');
}

print_r($urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
$pattern = "/href="([^\s"]+)/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

if (count($matches[1]) {
  foreach($matches[1] as $match)
    echo $match . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
$string = "<a href='test.php/url' class=>test</a>testar <a href='test2.php/url2' class=>test</a>";
$pattern = "/<a(?:[^>]*)href=([^ ]*)(?:[^>]*)>/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match){
    echo $match;
}
```